# Find next number in the sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

I want to share a question that is created by myself.

I will give a hint every 24 hours and my answer in 3 days given that nobody could answer my question.

5, 6, 2, 4, 0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6...

Comment: @hexomino, yeah typo ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the next element of the sequence is

> 1

Reasoning

> Index the days of the week as follow Monday=0, Tuesday=1,... Saturday=5, Sunday=6.
>  Then the sequence is the index of the 1st day of each month starting at February 2020.
>  That is February 1st = Saturday = 5, March 1st = Sunday = 6, etc.
>  The last element represents the 1st of December which is a Tuesday which has index 1.